# How to drag and drop a file FROM a C# WPF application TO another application which will open the file?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox, mp3

I am building a MP3 library application with WPF and C#. The application stores a list of MP3 file names and file locations, with the file names shown in a Listbox.

I want to be able to drag and drop an item from the Listbox into a third party music player application (such as Windows Media Player) so that it will open and start playing the file in exactly the same way that the music application would open and play a file dragged from a Windows explorer window. How can this be done?